# Azure App Service and Application Insights where is performance test?

Tags: azure, performance-testing, azure-web-app-service

So i'm trying some labs on Azure and one of them ask to create a performance test on an App Service.
The problem is that i can't seem to find it anywhere.
There is this link on the documentation but even with it i can't find it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-testing

Can someone tell me clearly where to find it ?

Comment: Have you read the text inside the fuchsia box at the top of the page you linked?  That should give you a hint.

Comment: Well... my guesses were right : the service has been disabled AND i'm blind ^^'.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web performance and load test functionality is deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where web performance and load testing will be available.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f38aaca5-4e31-473b-9a86-2f5c3df3e12a/web-performance-and-load-test-functionality-is-deprecated-visual-studio-2019-is-the-last-version?forum=vstest)

So you either need to downgrade to MSVS 2019 (or earlier) or consider using an alternative load testing tool, here you can find the [list](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) of free and open source load testing tools.

An example of comparison of the most advanced ones: [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)

Answer (score 0):

Just posting an answere here.
The service has been deprecated and is no longer available.
(at least there will be thread speaking of it because i didn't find one).